# What are some tools to make GUI for managing clouds of points

Tags: c++, user-interface

I have some code written in C++ that make some operation on a cloud of points expressed in X, Y, Z format and I need a tool to make a GUI to interact with these clouds other from Qt because it is very complicated.

I am looking for some tools specifically designed for managing data poins if possible.

Is there a way to run C++ programs using Matlab and making the display using matlab guide?